# Set Parameters Output Context from Looping on Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

i make some loop for calling data from firebase, how to set document id as parameters for my output context when i selected the data from document?

this my code for function daftaKota

```
function daftarKota(agent){
const query = db.collection('kota');
return query.get().then(s =>{
    if (s.empty){
        agent.add('belum ada kota yang didaftarkan oleh Pemilik');
        agent.add('untuk mengakses menu lainnya silahkan ketikan "menu"');
        agent.context.set('menu',2);
    } else {
      agent.add('berikut daftar kota');
      s.forEach(doc =>{
        agent.add(new Suggestion(doc.data().nama_kota));
        agent.context.set('lihat-toko',5,{'id_kota' : doc.id,'nama_kota' : doc.data().nama_kota});
      });
    }
});
```

this my code for function daftarToko

```
function daftarToko (agent){
const context = agent.context.get('lihat-toko');
const idKota = context.parameters.id_kota;
const nKota = agent.parameters.kota;

const query = db.collection('toko').where('id_kota','==',idKota);
return query.get().then(s =>{
  if (s.empty){
    agent.add('Belum ada Toko yang didaftarkan di kota ini');
    agent.add('untuk mengakses kota lainnya silahkan ketikan "kembali"');
    agent.context.set('order',2);
  }else{
    agent.add('berikut daftar toko di kota '+nKota);
    s.forEach(doc => {
      agent.add(new Card({title : doc.data().nama_toko, imageUrl : doc.data().gambar_toko}));
      agent.add(new Suggestion(doc.data().nama_toko));
      agent.context.set('lihat-kue',5,{'id_toko' : doc.id});
    });
  }
});
```

and this the Intent Map

```
intentMap.set('Daftar Kota',daftarKota);
intentMap.set('Daftar Toko',daftarToko);
```

this my intent "Daftar Kota"
[image: Intent Daftar Kota]

this intent show the city from database using suggestion
[image: Suggestion]

when i selected the other suggestion city like Yogyakarta, Jakarta, or Bandung, the parameters still set on Banjarmasin.

this my API response after i select Yogyakarta

```
{
  "responseId": "9e1daa4d-31f8-4a62-a939-813be357a634-19db3199",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "Yogyakarta",
    "parameters": {
      "kota": "Yogyakarta"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Belum ada Toko yang didaftarkan di kota ini"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "untuk mengakses kota lainnya silahkan ketikan \"kembali\""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/jastip-21e34/agent/sessions/771d2ffc-b490-51f3-7da7-78b91faa8ad3/contexts/order",
        "lifespanCount": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/jastip-21e34/agent/sessions/771d2ffc-b490-51f3-7da7-78b91faa8ad3/contexts/lihat-toko",
        "lifespanCount": 4,
        "parameters": {
          "kota": "Yogyakarta",
          "nama_kota": "Banjarmasin",
          "id_kota": "qCjS54XPf1lAtECUFTTw",
          "kota.original": "Yogyakarta"
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/jastip-21e34/agent/intents/f14ab0fa-b506-419d-a360-a8eb7cd84b93",
      "displayName": "Daftar Toko"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 236
    },
    "languageCode": "id"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "message": "Webhook execution successful"
  }
}
```

see at paramers :

1. i selected "kota : Yogyakarta",
2. but the id_kota is the document id of nama_kota "Banjarmasin", not the id of "Yogyakarta"

Comment: Please don't use graphics for something that is text (the JSON response), it can make it very difficult for some people to read.

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing the query that you're using, or where you're storing the parameters you get, but in your loop you're not actually checking to see if `nama_kota` matches the `kota` that is sent through the parameters. So it is changing the context every time it goes through the loop, and ends up with the new parameters from the last time through.

One solution would be to check if they match and, when they do, set the context.

```
  s.forEach(doc =>{
    agent.add(new Suggestion(doc.data().nama_kota));
    if( parameters.kota === doc.data().nama_kota ){
      agent.context.set('lihat-toko',5,{'id_kota' : doc.id,'nama_kota' : doc.data().nama_kota});
    }
  });
```

Comment: i try your recomendation code but at my Daftar Kota Intent i dont set any parameters.